# ORMlite Android not retrieving correct boolean values

Tags: android, sqlite, types, boolean, ormlite

I am having a similar problem to the following:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ormlite-user/V39vwKvQ1sI

I have an Oracle database with a boolean value stored as a 1 or 0 in a column of type NUMBER.  I am using Android ORMlite with the field defined as boolean.  The SQLite database on my device shows this column with "true" and "false" values.  Why is this?

Another problem I am experiencing as a result is the values returned from the QueryBuilder always have "false" as a value; I never see any "true" values returned.  I can see the correct values in the local database but they never get delivered to my loader.

Is this an issue with ORMlite failing to convert boolean values correctly?  Has this problem been fixed?

Comment: Is this really an Android issue?  Are you connecting to Oracle from an android app?  And I'm confused about how you are using Oracle and Sqlite at the same time?

Comment: Hi, @Gray.  I was actually thinking about emailing you.  Oracle is on the backend.  The data is transported to my device via XML, so there may be something else affecting this.  I tried to use a custom persister which treated the field as a Long, and that worked.  Ultimately, I just replaced the boolean with Long and that worked without a custom persister.

Comment: @Gray:  On the Android side, should boolean values normally be represented as true/false strings or 1/0 in SQLite?

Comment: SQLite doesn't care -- it is type-less.  ORMLite has made the choice to write booleans as numbers I believe.  I'm not sure why you see true/false in your sqlite database.

Comment: On the Android platform, does ORMLite normally write 1/0 for Boolean values?

Comment: It's supposed to, yes.  That's the default boolean field persister that ORMLite uses with Sqlite under Android.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions what I should check to see why true/false are being written out instead?

Comment: Upon further inspection, it appears that the getBoolean() method in AndroidDatabaseResults.java calls cursor.getShort().  If true/false is written out will this always return 0 or can it convert true/false to a short?

Comment: @Gray Do you think you could continue helping with this matter?  I sent an email through your mail filter system but I don't know if you received it.